RAG and LangChain for the Generative AI Chatbot to look at only the provided data
Requirements:

It would behaves like ChatGPT, however if user is asking something that is not in the provided data, it will say "Sorry, I do not know such information" <-- Please kindly refer to the example(s) below

Within organization only and not taking other sources other than the provided data below.

Only take up to 10 text file(s) for the data source, each of the file contains the information of 1 website.


This is what I think it should happen:
Example(s):

Whenever user is asking something like this to Generative AI Chatbot:

Who is the CEO of Google
Who is the CEO of Microsoft
Who is the CEO of Apple

It will say something like "Sorry, I do not know such information".


Whenever user is asking something like this to Generative AI Chatbot:

Who is the CEO

It will search through the provided data only and if not found will say "Sorry, I do not know such information".

Is there any free or paid subscriptions that I can use to achieve something like above? I am trying with ChatGPT, and it has global information and I am wondering is there anything that can be private use while using open-source LLMs, models, etc?
What I know is using RAG with LangChain, however how do I achieve this?
